# php - Indexed arrays without key

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get array without key,

Like current array is:

```
array([1]=>'one', [2]=>'two', [3]=>'three');
```

but I need this array without key, like this:

```
array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

please tell me how do I do that, I need to use this array as argument of a function, so it must have no keys.

Comment: Arrays will always have keys. But if you're trying to re-index the array with keys starting from `0`, then use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values).

Comment: it is generating keys, kindly check the example

Comment: You already have that array! All arrays have keys

Comment: is there no way to get array like this: `array('one', 'two', 'three');`

Answer (score 8):

Arrays always have keys, whether you want them or not. Even a simple `array('one', 'two', 'three');` will be `array([0] => 'one', [1] => 'two', [2] => 'three');`. That being said, your array does start with 1, and not with 0 (which is what want, I guess). To get the array starting at 0 you can use the  [array_values](https://www.php.net/array_values) function:

```
$new_array = array_values($old_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Your array N/B make sure it is a legal array. So for it to be an array and 
produce this example  : array([1]=>'one', [2]=>'two', [3]=>'three');
We use the same of array with no index, since every array comes indexed from 0.
 */

$array          = array('one','two','three');

//final array variable 
$finalArray     = array();

//encode the arry to Json
$jsonArray      = json_encode($array);
//first search & replace
$firstReplace   = str_replace('[','array(',$jsonArray);
//last search & replace
$finalArray     = str_replace(']',')',$firstReplace);
//output
print_r($finalArray);
```